# Ratio Distribution - Question about the solution on wolfram

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I just read the calculation of ratio distribution on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioDistribution.html). 
I found I cannot understand the following step (From the step 2 to step 3): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7VIp.png) 
$$ P(Y<=uX|X>0)+P(Y>=ux|X<0)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{ux}^0f(x,y)dydx$$
Could anyone explain it for me?
I think it is a conditional probability, so at least we need to divide it by P(X > 0) or P(X < 0). 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The probability being conditioned on cancels out for each piece.

\begin{align}
&P\left( \frac{Y}X  \leq u \right) \\
&= P(Y \leq uX~|~X>0) \cdot P(X>0) + P(Y \geq uX~|~ X<0)  \cdot P(X<0) \\
&= \frac{ \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)dydx }{ P(X>0) } \cdot P(X>0) + \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{ux}^0f(x,y)dydx }{ P(X<0) } \cdot P(X<0) 
\end{align}
where like you said yourself, the integral expression $\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{ux}^0f(x,y)dydx = P(Y \leq uX)$ is unconditional and needs to be divided by $P(X>0)$.

Note that the starting point $P\left( \frac{Y}X  \leq u \right)$ is unconditional, thus the final result should be unconditional as well. This couple of lines of derivation you see in the Wolfram page is just splitting the $X$-$Y$ plane into the disjoint regions via auxiliary conditioning.

Comment: Thank you sir! Now I understand the conditional probability, but I am confused about another point. In this problem, we just need to calculate $P(Y <= uX, X>0)$. But I think P(Y <= uX, X>0) should be $\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{ux}f(x,y)dydx$, rather than $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)dydx$.

Comment: In other words, I think the lower limit of integration on y is wrong.